# HTTP GET within AWS Lambda only works once

Tags: javascript, http, get, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to look up user profile information using the Amazon user profile API, but my GET request only works once. The first time, the profile information is returned no problem, but all subsequent calls to the lambda function cause the GET to return a 400 bad request. Here is my current code:

```
exports.handler = (event, context) => {
const alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
alexa.appId = APP_ID;
// console.log(event);
if (event.session.user.accessToken === undefined) {
    alexa.emit(':tellWithLinkAccountCard',
                  'To start using the app, please use the Alexa companion app to authenticate on Amazon');
} else {
    amazonProfileURL += event.session.user.accessToken;
    console.log(amazonProfileURL);
    http.get(amazonProfileURL, (res) => {
      const statusCode = res.statusCode;
      const contentType = res.headers['content-type'];

      let error;
      if (statusCode !== 200) {
        error = new Error(`Request Failed.\n` +
                          `Status Code: ${statusCode}`);
      } else if (!/^application\/json/.test(contentType)) {
        error = new Error(`Invalid content-type.\n` +
                          `Expected application/json but received ${contentType}`);
      }
      if (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        // consume response data to free up memory
        res.resume();
        return;
      }

      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      let rawData = '';
      res.on('data', (chunk) => rawData += chunk);
      res.on('end', () => {
        try {
            let parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData);
            user_name = parsedData.name;
            user_email = parsedData.email;
            console.log(user_name);
            console.log(user_email);
            alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
            alexa.execute();
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e.message);
        }
      });
    }).on('error', (e) => {
      console.log(`Got error: ${e.message}`);
    });
```

The first time calling the function, the code sucessfully runs the `alexa.execute()` function, but on all subsequent calls, the following is printed to the console:

```
START RequestId: 89a3a696-1442-11e7-9c15-6de8cce4b94d Version: $LATEST
2017-03-29T05:42:46.772Z    89a3a696-1442-11e7-9c15-6de8cce4b94d    https://api.amazon.com/user/profile?access_token=<long user access token>
2017-03-29T05:42:46.888Z    89a3a696-1442-11e7-9c15-6de8cce4b94d    Request Failed.
Status Code: 400
```

I am fairly new to JavaScript and AWS Lambda, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue. It turns out it was an AWS Lambda problem (feature?) rather than an HTTP GET problem. My `amazonProfileURL` string was persisting between calls to the lambda function so it was only a valid URL for the first call. The solution was to change that line to `requestURL = amazonProfileURL + event.session.user.accessToken` so that `amazonProfileURL` doesn't get overwritten.